# How can I listen Last.fm radio in Banshee?

Tags: banshee

Can I "love" tracks (on last.fm) that I'm listening to from Banshee? I know Rhythmbox can, but I see no such button in Banshee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that currently you can only love tracks you listen to on the Last.fm radios. See [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527373) for the upstream bug report about also loving tracks from your media library.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons are on the play control of Banshee, near the track title. I'm using Banshee 1.9.0 so your mileage may vary if you're using an older version.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.3 but I can't see it

Comment: I read the question wrong, its only with radio-played tracks as htorque mentioned.